# How to map java.util.Optional<Something> to Something? in Kotlin

Tags: java-8, kotlin, option-type

I have a method that returns `java.util.Optional<Something>`.
I want to use that method from Kotlin, and I want my result to be `Something?`, not `Optional<Something>`

How to do that in Kotlin, in idiomatic way?

calling `.orElse(null)` on `Optional` gives me `Something?` indeed, but it does not look good. Kotlin does not complain if I write  `val msg: Something = optional.orElse(null).` (`msg` is declared as  `Something`, not `Something?`- I loose compile-type check).

I use Kotlin 1.0.3

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Extend the java API with a method to unwrap `Optional`:

```
fun <T> Optional<T>.unwrap(): T? = orElse(null)
```

Then use it like you wanted:

```
val msg: Something? = optional.unwrap()  // the type is enforced
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html for details.

Comment: kotlin-stdlib has "or-null" functions (e.g. `firstOrNull`, `lastOrNull`, etc.). You might consider using "orNull` instead of "unwrap".

Comment: i'm looking at getting an Optional from a ?

Comment: @Stephane `fun <T> T?.asOptional(): Optional<T> = if (this != null) Optional.of(this) else Optional.empty())`

Comment: @bompf You're hired !

Answer (score 7):

If you use `com.google.common.base.Optional` (Guava library) then  `orNull()` is better.

For example,

```
// Java
public class JavaClass
  public Optional<String> getOptionalString() {
    return Optional.absent();
  }
}

// Kotlin
val optionalString = JavaClass().getOptionalString().orNull()
```

The definition of `orNull()`

```
/**
 * Returns the contained instance if it is present; {@code null} otherwise. If the instance is
 * known to be present, use {@link #get()} instead.
 *
 * <p><b>Comparison to {@code java.util.Optional}:</b> this method is equivalent to Java 8's
 * {@code Optional.orElse(null)}.
 */
@Nullable
public abstract T orNull();
```

Comment: Where did you find `orNull` method?

Comment: Using the auto-suggestion in Android Studio.

Comment: this is good for com.google.common.base.Optional from Guava.  java.util.Optional does not have orNull() method.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `java.util.Optional` support will be added to Kotlin 1.7 ([KT-50484](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50484/Extensions-for-java-util-Optional-in-stdlib)). Then [`optional.getOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm.optionals/java.util.-optional/get-or-null.html) will do it.

Another concise alternative would use [extension properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-properties):

```
val <T> Optional<T>.value: T?
    get() = orElse(null)
```

Usage:

```
val message: Something = optional.value ?: defaultMessage
```

Answer (score 1):

A nullable type in Kotlin can have value or null so you can convert and Optional to nullable Type as follows:

```
val str: SomeType? = Optional.of(SomeType_Value).map { it }.orElse(null)
```

For example for SomeType of String we have

```
val str: String? = Optional.of("someValue").map { it }.orElse(null)
```