# Check Key existense in Optional<> in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a variable of type Optional<>, which I retrieve from the database

Sample Optional<> type

```
 _id : 123456677,
    accounts: array,
    external_users: array
```

Code

```
val Account = accountRepository.findById(accountId)
 if (Account.isPresent){
    Account.get().accounts.add(data)
}
```

The Account is of type Optional<>. I want to check if the accounts array exists before adding data to it.In some cases, I won't have the accounts array in the collection. So I have to check if the array is present and then add the data, if it is not present I'll create the array

Comment: It seems you're interested in a *property* inside the object wrapped in `Optional`, not in the object itself, so the `Optional` wrapper has little relevance here. Please share how your class is defined, because the first snippet is not valid Kotlin. Is the `accounts` property nullable? It would help understand what you're trying to represent here. Also what is your error exactly? Compile time or runtime?

Comment: I have updated my model for Accounts. I'm getting the runtime error.

Comment: Here's a discussion on how to move from Java Optional to Kotlins model: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767376/how-to-map-java-util-optionalsomething-to-something-in-kotlin

Answer (score 1):

In the Kotlin world, Optional nullable syntax is natively supported at the grammatical level. Use the form of `object?.function(paramteter)` to determine whether it is nullable. If it is null, it will not be executed.

You can use the following method to judge the nullability

```kotlin
 
(accountRepository.findById(accountId)?.get()?.accounts ?: mutableSetOf<Accounts>()).let {
    add(data)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Getting error, if accounts array is not present.

Comment: Do you mean that an error occurs when adding data?

Comment: Yes, in some cases I won't have the accounts array in the collection. So I have to check if the array is present and then add the data, if it is not present I'll create the array.

Comment: I have updated the code, you can try to solve the problem.